# Binary file format vs Text-based format file size

Tags: c++, linux, qt, file-io, binary

I read that saving my files in binary-format was more compact than saving it in a text-based format. But how is it that my binary-format files are larger than the text-based one?

Here are the basics of the functions that I wrote. Both scanned the same directory. The binary-based file is always a few kilobytes larger.

Text-based:

```
void oldSave(){
    QFile file("sentry.dat");
    QTextStream out(&file);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDir dir = dirSelect;

    out << "Directory: " << dirSelect << endl; 
    //prepend directory from which scan was selected to begin from

    out << QCryptographicHash::hash(hashFile.readAll(),
              QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex()
        << " : " << hashFile.fileName() << "\n";
```

Binary-based:

```
 void saveFile(){
    QFile file("sentry.dat");
    QDataStream out(&file);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDir dir = dirSelect;

    out << dirSelect;
    out << QCryptographicHash::hash(hashFile.readAll(), QCryptographicHash::Md5) 
        << hashFile.fileName();
```

Comment: Are you sure you know the precise size of each file? Depending on how your file finder reports sizes, you might be seeing an artifact of the way your OS manages blocks of data on the hard drive. You might try writing a little program to read each file and count the bytes to eof.

Comment: You should write a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also, inspect the contents of the file using a hex editor to know how the data is saved and you should see the difference. Outputting an MD5 in binary should have half the size than the string version.

Comment: The `toHex` method may be converting a internal representation in an ASCII Hex conversion.  For example, the value 0x25 (internal representation of 1 byte) may be converted to 0x30, 0x78, 0x32, 0x35, which is the ASCII codes for '0', 'x', '2', '5'.  Thus expanding a binary file by 4x (with preceeding "0x") or by 2x (without the "0x").

Answer (score 1):

The statement "saving files in binary-format was more compact than saving it in a text-based format" is meaningless. After all, writing into a binary file writes the exact size of the instance, whereas you decide how the output text file is formatted. Ask yourself, how is `operator<<()` defined on `QDir` and `QTextStream`?

Unless the output binary file is unusually large, you shouldn't worry about the slight increased filesize if input and output are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

May be [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/asciiBin.html) tutorial put a light on this question. Please, read the section

> The Difference between ASCII and Binary Files?

. Moreover, think again with UTF-8 (of course need more space than ASCII) instead of ASCII and you will understand the difference in size.

Comment: ASCII is a subset of Unicode and UTF-8 encodes the common characters with identical bytes. So, unless you are storing ASCII in packed 7-bit structures, every possible ASCII string is the same size as the same string in UTF-8.

Comment: @Tom, thank you, I forgot this detail (not consider this specific case also).

Answer (score 1):

Review the `toHex` method.  Hint:  Assign the output of `toHex` to a string and look at the string with a debugger.

The toHex method may be converting a internal representation in an ASCII Hex conversion. For example, the value 0x25 (internal representation of 1 byte) may be converted to 0x30, 0x78, 0x32, 0x35, which is the ASCII codes for '0', 'x', '2', '5'. Thus expanding a binary file by 4x (with preceeding "0x") or by 2x (without the "0x").